# NDK Debug for Nexus 9 arm64-v8a build not working for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, arm64

I keep getting the following error:

```
[2015-01-23 19:27:47 - NativeTestApp] Unable to find a compatible ABI    
[2015-01-23 19:27:47 - NativeTestApp] ABI's supported by the application: armeabi
[2015-01-23 19:27:47 - NativeTestApp] ABI's supported by the device: arm64-v8a, null
```

when my Application.mk is empty.  When I have an Application.mk and I set APP_ABI to arm64-v8a, all it says is:

```
[2015-01-23 19:33:27 - NativeTestApp] Unknown Application ABI:     
[2015-01-23 19:33:27 - NativeTestApp] arm64-v8a
[2015-01-23 19:33:27 - NativeTestApp] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

Seems to me like the application wants to compile armeabi but the target is arm64.  It works fine when not running as native debug.

Comment: Also, as long as I set APP_PLATFORM := android-19 (and my manifest), debug DOES work for the Nexus 10 tablet running that version.  So I do not think it is Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an inherent bug with ndk-r10d and previous versions.  This has been fixed with ndk-r10e, although it still does not work with eclipse since eclipse has its own ndk plugins.  Google apparently intends on having ndk-gdb compatibility with the next Android Studio release.

EDIT:  Sources:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#rel

"Fixed ndk-gdb for 64-bit ABIs. (Issue 118300)".

Answer (score 1):

Native C/C++ debugging on 64-bit CPU equipped devices is not supported by the latest official version of ADT plugin for Eclipse (23.0.7).

I managed to update the sources to get the NDK debugging work on arm64-v8a (Nexus 9).

Try out this patched version: https://github.com/khaledev/ADT